# how to save the http.request curl in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I already managed to make a post request of curl in rails
I print on the console the response.body

```
{"access_token":"XXXXXXX","public_key":"XXXXXX","refresh_token":"XXXXXX","live_mode":false,"user_id":XXXX,"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":15552000,"scope":"offline_access read write"}
```

now I want to gurantee that data in a table in rails

How can you do that?

```
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want from us to help you... you want a table? create a migration. you want to store the response data in there? the table should probably have a json column - then you'd create a model that matches that table and do `MyModel.create(data: response.body)` or something in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want is to make a HTTP request then parse the response and store it into a table (model) in your database. Well if that is the case:

```
require 'net/https'
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/path")
// You can change the request method to whatever method you want
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = { //json hear in case you need it }
request.add_field 'token', 'XXXXX'
response = http.request(request).body
json_response = JSON.parse(response, symbolize_names: true)
```

You will have the response in `json_response`, then you only will have to store that information in the model you want:

`Model.create(attribute_1: json_response[:parameter_1], attribute_2: json_response[:parameter_2]...)`